# jQuery UI sortable sync with array (using clone option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an unordered list which I'd like to order using `jQuery UI sortable`. In general everything works well. But I want to sync the order with an array datasource.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$('#jw_sortable').sortable({axis: 'y', handle: '.handle', start: sortStart, change: sortApply, helper: 'clone'});

function sortStart(event, ui) {
    ui.item.fromIndex = ui.item.index();
}
function sortApply(event, ui) {
    var index = ui.placeholder.index();
    index = ((ui.item.fromIndex < index) ? index - 1 : index);

    dataSource.move(ui.item.fromIndex, index); // using a prototype function

    ui.item.fromIndex = index;
}
```

This actually works. But only if I release the mouse button between the actions. I'd rather like to update the position (thus I set `ui.item.fromIndex = index` in the last line).

But this does not work. I think it bas something to do with the several placeholder and helper elements that are created next to the moved elements (when using `index()`).

How can I get the "correct" fromIndex and toIndex each `change` event call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made it. I just had to find the index of the placeholder without respecting the (hidden) original item. So this is what I came up with:

```
function sortApply(event, ui) {
    var index = ui.placeholder.parent().children('li:visible').index(ui.placeholder);

    dataSource.move(ui.item.fromIndex, index);

    ui.item.fromIndex = index;
}
```